# Jackson and unmarshalling Spring HATEOAS references

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-boot

I have a `Spring Boot` REST application which also include dependencies to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-hateoas`.

My issue is want to convert a JSON payload being posted to my server.

The payload contains data to create a new `Product` with a relation to a existing `VAT Rate`.
This relation is modeled using a JPA @ManyToOne like:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private VatRate vatRate;
```

When I post something like:

```
{ 
  "description": "bla",
  "price": 99.99,
  "vat_rate": {
    "id": 1
}
```

Jackson automatically converts I can persist a new Product with a relation to the given VAT Rate.

However as I'm using HATEOAS I think I should use something like:

```
{ 
  "description": "bla",
  "price": 99.99,
  "vat_rate": {
    "id": "http://somehost/vat-rates/1"
}
```

But this one fails as Jackson cannot convert it.

Is there a easy solution for this? As HATEOAS is not a solid requirement in my case, if this is not possible easily it will put a to high burden to use HATEOAS.

Next to that if in first example I provide a unknown vat_rate id Boot gives me back a 500.
Reason is that Jackson references/creates a `VAT Rate` which does not exists and when trying to store the `Product` a FK violation happens resulting in the 500 due to a  org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.
I think it would be better to return a 400 pointing out that vat_rate does not exists.
But probably I have to check the existence of the `VAT Rate` manually before saving the `Product`.

Comment: You've tagged the question with spring-data-rest, but have only mentioned spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in the question. Are you using Spring DATA REST, or are you using Spring HATEOAS and implementing the controllers yourself?

Comment: I'm implementing the controllers myself. I'll try to remove the tag.

Comment: PS @AndyWilkinson I'm always struggling with JSON input. For output the Spring HATEOAS resource assemblers a really nice. For JSON input I'm still looking for a good pattern. There are not many examples related to processing input, do you know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, I like to use a separate DTO that's passed into my controller methods, rather than trying to reuse the JPA entity. In this scenario I'd create a `ProductInput` class with three properties:

```
class ProductInput {
    private String description;
    private String price;
    private URI vatRate;
}
```

The `vatRate` property is a `URI` as it's referencing an existing VAT rate resource and, when you're using hypermedia, a URI is a resource's id.

In your controller you then need to use this `URI` to look up a `VatRate` instance. You can use `UriTemplate` to extract the id from the `URI` and then use the id to look it up. Something like this:

```
String idString = new UriTemplate(/vat-rates/{id})
        .match(productInput.getVateRate().toASCIIString()).get("id");
long id = Long.valueOf(idString);
VatRate vatRate = vatRateRepository.findById(id);
if (vatRate == null) {
    // Return an appropriate error response, probably a 400
    // …
} else {
    // Create and save the product
    // …
}
```

I've got a [very basic app that uses Spring HATEOAS](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-restdocs/tree/master/rest-notes-spring-hateoas) on Github that might provide some useful further reading.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I was using this approach with a separate Input / Payload class. The UriTemplate is a good I should look into this as well. I will definitely checkout your app for further reading.